# How to recreate a list of dictionaries after cleaning the dictionary key-value pairs

Tags: python, list

I have a list of dictionaries containing 80K records in the format given below -

```
{'system_name': 'aapvir004', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'X2AIX_GDSS\n'}
{'system_name': 'aapvir003', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'X2AIX_GDSS\n'}
{'system_name': 'aapvir002', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'X2AIX_GDSS\n'}
{'system_name': 'abpvir004', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'X2AIX_GDSS\n'}
{'system_name': 'nappir002.1dc.com', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 
 'LAC.BRAZIL.GIO.LINUX'}
{'system_name': 'nappir001.1dc.com', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 
 'LAC.BRAZIL.GIO.LINUX'}
{'system_name': 'aapvtl001', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 'X2AIX_GDSS\n'}
{'system_name': 'nbpvwb007.1dc.com', 'fdc_inv_sa_team': 
 'LAC.BRAZIL.GIO.LINUX'}
```

The method getResource() performs data cleansing.

```
def getResource(self):
     try:
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        for row in data:
            sys_name = [row["system_name"],]
            team = [row["fdc_inv_sa_team"]]
            arg1 = re.sub('.1DC.com|.1dc.com|.1dc.COM |.1DC.COM\\b', '', str(sys_name))
            arg2 = str(team).replace('\\n', '')
            arg1 = str(arg1.strip('"[]"'))
            arg2 = str(str(arg2).strip("[]"))
```

I want to recreate the list of dictionaries using arg1 and arg2 in the method and return it. Could you please suggest a feasible way to do so?

Comment: This looks like a list of dictionaries? Although technically it's just a bunch of dictionaries being created, as there's no list.

Comment: So basically you want to do some cleaning formatting on the elements of the list, right?

Comment: @TomWyllie yes, you are right! It is a list of dictionaries. My bad.

Comment: @AymanNedjmeddine I want to recreate the list of dictionaries after cleaning the data based on arg1 and arg2

Comment: @TomWyllie edited my question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @TanuSachdeva Thanks for explaining. I've added an answer.

Comment: @AymanNedjmeddine Thanks, it works like a charm. :)

Comment: @TanuSachdeva You're most welcome :)

Comment: @AymanNedjmeddine next step for me is to return this modified list of dictionaries and use it as an argument in another method to update the database. I am getting "ERROR - Error 1054: Unknown column 'n3bvap049' in 'where clause' error. It was working fine with the old code format. Do you want me to create a new question for this or will you be able to help in the same thread?

Comment: @TanuSachdeva, I've joined the chat room you created. Let's talk over there.

Comment: @AymanNedjmeddine I am not able to join the chat room. It does not open on my office laptop.

Comment: @TanuSachdeva, [Here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149410/discussion-between-tanu-sachdeva-and-ayman-nedjmeddine) is the link. If you can't join still, please make a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an index to loop through your array

```
for i in range(len(l)):
  sys_name = l[i]["system_name"]
  team = l[i]["fdc_inv_sa_team"]

  # do whatever
  sys_name = re.sub('.1DC.com|.1dc.com|.1dc.COM |.1DC.COM\\b', '', str(sys_name))
  sys_name = str(sys_name.strip('"[]"'))
  team = str(team).replace('\n', '')
  team = str(str(team).strip("[]"))

  l[i]["system_name"] = sys_name
  l[i]["fdc_inv_sa_team"] = team
```

Note: This changes the array in-place. Meaning without creating a new one but modifying that list itself

Answer (score 1):

Create a list outside of your loop, add dictionaries to it using `arg1` and `arg2`, and then return it.

```
output = []
for row in data:
    # ...
    arg1 = ...
    arg2 = ...
    output.append({'system_name': arg1, 'fdc_inv_sa_team': arg2})
return output
```

Comment: Used the same approach but got "typeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" @Jared Goruen

Comment: @TanuSachdeva Then post the code that resulted in that exception, with the full traceback.